# Cross-platform resource usage on subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, cpu, popen, ram

*First of all if this has been asked before I'm sorry for the duplicate, but I couldn't find the answer to my question anywhere.*

So, I am pretty new to Python, and I am currently working on a wrapper for a web application.
This wrapper starts a subprocess using Popen and then sends information about that subprocess to the web application. Everything is working great so far.

Now the only question I have is; **Is it possible to get resource usage of a subprocess (*RAM and CPU*)?**

If so, how would I go about doing that? Something cross-platform would be awesome, but a different method for Windows, Mac and Linux would work as well.

If it isn't possible to get via subprocess. How would I got about fetching resource usage from another process?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`psutil`](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/) provides a cross-platform solution to get resource usage of a subprocess e.g.:

```
import random
import psutil # $ pip install psutil

p = psutil.Process(random.choice(psutil.pids()))
print(p.name())
print(p.cpu_times())
print(p.memory_info())
```

to get the info for an existing `subprocess.Popen` instance just pass `popen_instance.pid` to `psutil.Process`. You could also create a subprocess using [`psutil.Popen`](http://psutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#popen-class) directly.