# Program getting stuck when using subprocess.Popen() or subprocess.check_call()

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I want to run a program from python and find its memory usage. To do so I am using:

```
l=['./a.out','<','in.txt','>','out.txt']
p=subprocess.Popen(l,shell=False,stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
p.wait()
Res= getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN)
print Res.ru_maxrss
```

I also tried to use `check_call(l,shell=False,stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)` and remove p.wait but the problem is program is getting stuck at p.wait() when using Popen and at `check_call()` when using check_call(). I am not able to figure out why this is happening. Is my argument list wrong.

The command `./a.out < in.txt > out.txt` is working fine on terminal. I am using Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues (at least):

1. `<`, `>` redirection is handled by a shell. `subprocess` doesn't spawn a shell by default (you shouldn't either)
2. If `stdout=PIPE`, `stderr=PIPE` then you must read from the pipes otherwise the process may block forever

To make a subprocess read from a file and write to a file:

```
from subprocess import check_call, STDOUT

with open('in.txt') as file, open('out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    check_call(["./a.out"], stdin=file, stdout=outfile, stderr=STDOUT)
```

`stderr=STDOUT` merges stdout, stderr.

Comment: Okay I got it... I know my next question is off topic but the scheme I used to calculate memory usage of program being executed is not returning the correct answer. I want to know how can I get the max memory usage.

Comment: [Cross-platform resource usage on subprocess.Popen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22715059/4279)

Comment: I tried using psutil but I have one doubt. If the process gets over before reaching `psutil.Process(p.pid)` then what will happen. and sometimes the output (rss=0,vms=0) appears what does that mean? But in the subsequent runs it displays almost correct memory usage.

Comment: still the same problem the output is (rss=0,vms=0) for initial runs but subsequently after some runs I get the correct output

Comment: I don't know, why `psutil` returns `0` (it might be mentioned in the docs). Here's [code example that reports maximum memory for a current process](https://gist.github.com/zed/8b05c3ea0302f0e2c14c). You could ask why `psutil` returns 0,0 for memory as [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (if you know already then [post your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)).

Answer (score 1):

You are using shell redirection characters in your call, but when you use `subprocess`, and set `shell=False`, you have to handle those pipes manually.
You seem to be passing those redirection characters directly as arguments to the `a.out` program.
Try running this in your shell:

```
./a.out '<' in.txt '>' out.txt
```

See if `a.out` terminates then as well.

Comment: `./a.out<in.txt>out.txt` is working fine on terminal

Comment: @user2179293, I have not seen this in the original question, thanks for bringing this to my attention. I have now edited the answer, please take a look.

Comment: Ok I get it the input is not getting redirected. How can I redirect my input? I dont want to use `shell=True` because while calculating the memory usage the program calculates the memory usage of shell and not the program in case of `shell=True`